# Creating a line chart

Tags: reporting-services, types, line, charts

Can I create a line chart that looks like the one(which I have provided as a link. Please click the link to see the chart image) using SSRS 2008? If so, please help me how to do that?

Please see the below link for sample 
http://i48.tinypic.com/20ib1v8.png

Answer (score 0):

Yes, assuming your data source already supplies P3 incidents that achieved response SLA.

- Insert a line chart
- Add a category group to be the month of the incident
- Add a value for P3 incidents that achieved response SLA, based on the dataset
- Add another value for the Service Level Target, as =0.95.